# Laravel web-Socket installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-websockets

I want to install Laravel Web-Socket package but I face some errors when I run this command
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets

Using version ^1.12 for beyondcode/laravel-websockets
Running composer update beyondcode/laravel-websockets --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.65, found laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

And here is my composer.json :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/larAavel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},

"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simple do one thing

remove composer.lock file and then install your required package